# What is the difference? "Kate watched TV a lot when/while she was sick last year"

Tags: difference

What is the difference between these two sentences?

1. Kate watched TV a lot when she was sick last year.
2. Kate watched TV a lot while she was sick last year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**When** refers to time  on a time-line. The time can be a point in time:

> When the clock strikes four...

or a stretch of time:

> When I was a child...
>
> When she was sick...

That is, in the phase of life we call "childhood", which is preceded by infancy and followed by adolescence, etc.  At that time in the past when she was ill. The time is "located" on an implied time-line.

**While** cannot refer to a point-in-time:

<sup>ungrammatical</sup>While midnight arrives...

It refers only to a stretch of time, a duration, not on a time-line, unrelated to linear time.

> While she was ill...

That is, during her illness.   The illness is not represented as having come after something and before something.

Comment: So... You've done a great job of explaining the difference (which is what the OP requested)... but are they both valid constructions? I'm unsure based on your answer.

Comment: "Both" being "when she was sick" and "while she was sick"?

Comment: Yes! Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: When dinosaurs roamed the earth, humankind had not yet arrived.

Comment: While dinosaurs roamed the earth, pterodactyls took to the skies.

Comment: This is a good distinction, although I think in real conversation most native speakers wouldn't see a difference.

Comment: Knowledge of these time distinctions is deep in the subconscious and that is where these linguistic choices are made in natural conversation between native speakers; even if they could not articulate the differences, the (overwhelming) majority of native speakers would know that **when** and **while** cannot be swapped in the first dinosaur sentence,  and not without changing the meaning in the second dinosaur sentence.

Answer (score 2):

To my mind, there's little difference.

The first statement says that *when Kate was sick, she watched a lot of TV*, and the second one *focuses a bit more* on the fact that she watched a lot of TV *throughout the whole period* of her illness.